# GetEval WebDriver

Tags: webdriver

how to use command `getEval()` in webdriver? 
here Selenium RC (1) code:

```
String date2 = selenium.getEval("var d=new Date(); d.getDate()+'.'+(((d.getMonth()) < 10 ? \"0\" + (d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1)) +'.'+d.getFullYear();");
```

How can I use it in webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String date2 = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
"var d=new Date(); d.getDate()+'.'+(((d.getMonth()) < 10 ? \"0\" + (d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1)) +'.'+d.getFullYear();");
```

Comment: I _think_ that `executeScript()` doesn't automatically return the last line like Selenium 1 did, does it? Add a `return`... Also, [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) is the documentation for this.

Comment: Jochen, your script is right, but we need in "return" too, thanks for Slanec. Here is right code: String date2  = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var d=new Date();return d.getDate()+'.'+(((d.getMonth()) < 10 ? \"0\" + (d.getMonth()+1) : d.getMonth()+1)) +'.'+d.getFullYear();");

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use date method only to generate random numbers, use this method:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmSS");
Date date = new Date();
String randomInteger = format.format(date);
return randomInteger;
```

You can use this code in Selenium RC and webdriver as well.