# I have generated the random number using below code in Selenium RC, but it is not working in Webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

For random number generation in Selenium RC, I have the code but it is not working properly in Webdriver. If I use the below code in webdriver, it is returning null. Please find the code below in webdriver

```
String Randnum = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var d=new Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getDate().toString()" +
            "+new Date().getDay()" +
            "+new Date().getHours()" +
            "+new Date().getMinutes()" +
            "+new Date().getSeconds()" +
            "+new Date().getMilliseconds()");
```

Please help me out on this... Help will be appreciated.

Comment: you could have commented at the original post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125483/geteval-webdriver/13816212) and could have got a better / quicker answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have commented & added the same question at the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you try the same thing using Java?

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
String randomName = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks Santoshsarma for your answer. Even using this code, i am able to generate the random number.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement. Without, the javascript will run but not return anything.

```
String Randnum = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return new Date().getFullYear() + new Date().getDate().toString() + new Date().getDay() + new Date().getHours() + new Date().getMinutes() + new Date().getSeconds() + new Date().getMilliseconds()");
```

Comment: Yes Arran, Thanks for the answer. I have tried both the answers, I am able to generate the Random number using the above code.

Comment: This question can be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the javascript code below

```
function displayRandum()
{

     var d = new Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getDate().toString() + new Date().getDay() + new Date().getHours()+new Date().getMinutes() + new Date().getSeconds()+new Date().getMilliseconds();
     alert(d);

}
```

works perfectly. Can you try in your Selenium code, to keep everything in one line (no extra "+" and  "  characters).

**Edit: (missed return statement. Saw Arran's reply and realized it).**

```
function returnRandum()
{

     var d = new Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getDate().toString() + new Date().getDay() + new Date().getHours()+new Date().getMinutes() + new Date().getSeconds()+new Date().getMilliseconds();
     return d;

}
```